# Ignore ending character if a other character was found (find the scope in code)

Tags: c++, regex, scope

I'm currently trying how to use Regex in C++ for more advanced stuff like creating my own coding language (just for the fun of it) and I'm having a bit of a problem with reading out the scope of the code.

I'm currently using this text to test my Regex against,

```
private char test;
public static int foo = 0;
private int var = 0;
private void run(char data, int add) 
{
     var += 50 + add;
     print (var + test, asdm, asf.getString());
     if (var == 70) {
        print("yes");
     }
}
```

And the regex I'm using to read out the scope of run and the if-statement within it is,

```
\{([\S\s]*?)\}
```

This is what it matches atm

```
{
    var += 50 + add;
    print (var + test, asdm, asf.getString());
    if (var == 70) {
        print("yes");
    }
```

The problem is that it find a } before the actual } it needs, I'd like to know if there is a way to go around this and capture each individual scope as it's own part.

I've tried messing around with loopbacks but I keep getting the error 'The expression contained mismatched ( and )' even though it should be valid regex. Edit, I found out that the c++ version of regex (default one) does not support lookbehind which is why it didn't work.

Comment: Regular expressions can't match balanced expressions, unless it has the recursion extension that a few regexp engines have.

Comment: SCNR: http://i.imgur.com/dkbyB.jpg

Comment: If you're creating a language, you should be using a parser generator like `bison`. Regular expressions are OK for recognizing individual tokens, but you should use a grammar for recognizing large scale structure of the language.

Comment: I've taken a very quick look at bison but it seems like that requires a pre-defined grammar file to parse the code and it needs a new grammar file each time.. I'll take a look at it once I've got some more time available.